# What are differences between PageList, ValueList and Code-Pega-List?

Tags: pega

I run into a question about differences between PageList/ValueList and Code-Pega-List.

I know that

1) ValueList is a group of elementary type elements, which has unique index.

2) PageList is an indexed group of complex elements.

But what about class Code-Pega-List? Where I am allowed to utilize it?

When I was researching that question, I found out, that PageList or ValueList property cannot be passed as parameter where is awaited Code-Pega-List type property.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, *Page List* and *ValueList* is property types such as for example *Page*, *Single Property*, *Page Group*, etc. You can create property any type applies to any class, for example `@baseclass`.

`Code-Pega-List` is class. Class consist of several properties any types (Page, Page List, etc.). You can open class `Code-Pega-List` in application explorer and see it.

`Code-Pega-List` is a core class for Pega Platform. Many rules used it, such as methods in `activity` rule (`Obj-Browse`), `report definition` rule, etc. This class contains standard logic, for example count of elements in page-list contain in property  `.pxResults`. I think that my answer help you understand difference.